# Equivariant Hartogs: extending $G$-equivariant vector bundle to codimension 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a normal variety with an action of $G$ and $X_0 \subset X$ be an open $G$-invariant subset whose complement is of codimension at least 2. Every vector bundle on $X_0$ extends to a vector bundle on $X$ (see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112329/vector-bundles-on-normal-surfaces), for example). Is the same true for $G$-equivariant vector bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can extend just the vector bundle. Then you should check that the equivariant structure extends. The latter amounts to some morphisms $g^*E \to E$ for $g \in G$, so in the end the question is in extension of functions, which exists by Hartogs.

Comment: Sasha, thank you, but it gives an action of $G$ on $E$ that is algebraic on $E|_{X_0}$, is it also algebraic on $E$?

Comment: The extension maps $g^*E \to E$ are algebraic, hence so is the action.

Comment: Sasha, by algebraicity I mean that $G \times E \to E$ is algebraic, not only its fibers $\{g\} \times E \to E$.

Comment: You never mentioned that $G$ is algebraic (I thought it is finite). But it doesn't matter much, you should just extend the map $a^*E \to p^*E$, where $a$ and $p$ are the action and the projection maps $G \times X \to X$. Since the complement of $G \times X_0$ in $G \times X$ has codimension at least 2, the extension exists (and unique).